# F1 season database individual races

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, database-design

I'm making a C#/SQL/LINQ web form site to handle a single season in Formula 1. The tricky part appears to be designing tables for single races, each describing around 20 drivers, teams they drive with (2 drivers per team, not necessarily the same drivers all season) and position in the race.

So far I have the tables

```
Driver (driverid(PK), firstname, lastname, teamid(FK)
Team (teamid(PK), teamname, engine)
Circuit (circuitid, circuitname, country)
```

For storing race results I have a Race table

```
dbo.Race

raceId(PK)
date
circuitId(FK)
```

and a table for each race with 20 records which will be linked to corresponding entry in Race (analogous to an List as a class field in object-oriented design) eg.

```
dbo.Australia2018

driverid(FK)
teamid(FK)
finalposition
finaltime
```

The alternative to having a new table for each race was to have 20 other fields in the Race table but either way there is a lot of data to be stored. Obviously I need to search through each race to total points for Drivers and Constructors (Team) results.

For this amount of data there will be no 'correct' way of designing, but is there a neater way I'm missing here?

Comment: You are missing some basic experience on relational databases. You should design a table for the race results where you store the raceid, the driverid, the teamid and the other attributes like points/position/time. Everything result related goes in this table. (Also this pattern should be used to link the Team with the Driver. Use a table that links a Team with a Driver with the attributes describing the start and end date for the relationship between the Team and the Driver)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you wanted.

You could create a table for each driver, this would hold all of the information about that driver, it would also have a foreign key for the team they belong to. This would allow you to query all drivers & teams seperately to races.

```
CREATE TABLE Driver
(
Driver_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Forename varchar(100),
Surname varchar(100),
Team_ID INT
)
```

You could use a linking table to link the driver to the team and when their realationship started and ended

```
CREATE TABLE Driver_Team
(
Driver_Team_ID INT IDENEITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Team_ID INT,
Driver_ID INT,
Start_date datetime,
End_date datetime
)
```

There would be another table for the teams, all team information could live here.

```
CREATE TABLE Teams
(
Team_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Team_Name varchar(100) 
)

ALTER TABLE Driver ADD CONSTRAINT FK_TeamID FOREIGN KEY (Team_ID) REFERENCES Teams (Team_ID)
```

A table for the circuits or tracks, here you could put all information about the track

```
CREATE TABLE Circuit
(
Circuit_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
CircuitName varchar(200)
)
```

Now the race table you would have the driver id, team id and circuit id these are foreign keys from other tables, then you could have all the other race information such as the race date, final position and final time

```
CREATE TABLE Race
(
Race_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Race_Date DATETIME,
Driver_ID INT,
Team_ID INT,
Circuit_ID INT,
FinalPosition TINYINT,
Final_Time DATETIME
)

ALTER TABLE Race ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Race_DriveID FOREIGN KEY (Race_ID) REFERENCES Driver(Race_ID);
ALTER TABLE Race ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Race_Team FOREIGN KEY (Team_ID) REFERENCES Teams(Team_ID);
ALTER TABLE Race ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Race_CircuitID FOREIGN KEY (Circuit_ID) REFERENCES Circuit(Circuit_ID);
```

Once you have all of your data in the tables you could select the data from the database using something like this.

```
SELECT 

D.Forename,
D.Surname,
T.TeamName,
C.CircuitName,
R.FinalPosition,
R.Final_Time

FROM Race R

INNER JOIN Driver D ON 
D.Driver_ID = R.Driver_ID

INNER JOIN Teams T ON
T.Team_ID = R.Team_ID

INNER JOIN Circuits C ON
C.Circuit_ID = R.Circuit_ID

WHERE C.CircuitName = 'Silverstone' AND D.Forename = 'Lewis'
```